# keyboard not working right after installation or after updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, keyboard

so I have a dual boot with windows 11. When I first installed ubuntu, my keyboard wasnt working and the only thing that helped was resetting my BIOS  (shorting 2 pins on my motherboard), after that I boot into advanced options ubuntu, and my keyboard works for some time, but some time later (maybe a week) my keyboard stops working again so I do the same thing and it starts working.
note that when the keyboard doesnt work, it doesnt work even during boot, so I cant just boot into the advanced options, I have to short the two pins every time, anybody can help please?

Comment: Is your keyboard a PS2 or USB one? And what are the manufacturer and type of your keyboard and your mainboard?

Comment: its a usb one, SPC GEAR GK550, by mainboard im guessing you mean motherboard, which is a Gigabyte B650M, sorry didnt think to put this into the question..